# Render numpy array on screen in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pygame, pygame-surface

I'm trying to render a numpy array, that is, its content to a screen in pygame.
However, pygame text renderer only supports Unicode.

I tried to convert my array to chararray, but it wasn't a solution.

Are there any function in numpy that converts an array to a string, while maintaining the shape.
Another approach was parsing the numpy array to string; albeit it worked, the array lost its shape.

Here's my code.

```
    import pygame
    import numpy as np

    pygame.init()
    pygame.font.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
    b = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                 [3, 5, 6, 5]])

    print(b)
    running = True
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 20)

    while running:

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        text = font.render(b, False, (255, 255, 255))

        screen.blit(text, (30, 30))

        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```

Comment: Pygame doesn't have multiline text rendering. You could iterate over the array and then font.render and blit row by row and increment the y coordinate. I think there are third party modules that handle multiline text, but I can't say anything about their quality (I've only checked out one before but it looked like a beginner project).

Answer (score 1):

I believe `np.array_str(b)` does what you want. Check the docs on [`np.array_str`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_str.html).

It literally returns `the string representation of the data in the array`. quoted from the doc that also matches your request.

Comment: It still doesn't keep the shape, though. That is, it's not representing a rowXcol array.

Comment: It does. At least in string mode. Pygame might not be recognizing line break character `\n`.

Comment: @CastFellow If you want more detailed control  on how to format the string check [array2string](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html#numpy.array2string)